# ambiguous methods to load .bin models in gensim

Tags: gensim

There is an ambiguity between ways how to load pretrained models into gensim.
For .vec files and fin_vec = path_to_vec_model

```
de_model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(fin_vec)
```

works just fine. In the gensim documentation it says for .bin files I should add binary = TRUE, but for fin_bin = path_to_bin_model

```
de_model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(fin_bin, binary = TRUE)
```

Throws the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

The gensim documentation also tates that for bin models one should use:

```
from gensim.models import FastText
de_model = gensim.models.fasttext.load_facebook_model(fin_bin)
```

Which loads the model but then it seems impossible to run the word analogy queries

```
sims = de_model.most_similar(positive=["mother", "queen"], negative= "father"], topn=5)
AttributeError: 'FastText' object has no attribute 'most_similar'
```

I understand that I can try and use `model.wv.most_similar` but I would like to strictly compare two models and not use different tools in doing so. Ideally I would like to load the bin model using something like `de_model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(fin_bin, binary = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not enough to look at a file with a `.bin` extension & know its format.

Many very differently-formatted files tend to use that extension, so extra context about where a file came from is needed to know how such a file should be loaded, and choosing the wrong loading method can cause errors.

The `.load_word2vec_format()` methods are only appropriate for files with plain lists-of-word-vectors, in a line-oriented format used by (among others) the original `word2vec.c` code release by Google.

So, what's the filename of the file you're trying to load, and where did it come from, and what explanation of its creation/format was provided along with the file?

Those will help resolve which method is appropriate.

Note also that `binary = TRUE` is not idiomatic or wise Python. The Python boolean true value is named `True`, or implied by many nonzero/nonempty objects, whereas the meaning of the variable `TRUE` will depend on prior code, which you've not shown, and is prone to errors that are impossible if using the standard/idiomatic (& PEP8) style or parameter specification `binary=True`.

Further, some generations of software that writes certain formats may have used encodings, or been looser about token contents, that certain generations of reading software may have trouble reading.

So, especially if hitting an error, you should collect info about the versions of software that wrote, and failed-to-read, the file in question. (Another debugging probe that can be done with the `.load_word2vec_format()` method is to use the optional `limit` argument to only read a set number of word from the front of the file.

Because that format – plain or 'binary=True' – includes all word-vectors in a simple line-by-line format, if via probes you find that loading with `limit=n` works, but `limit=n+1` gives a format-related error, the problem is  at about line `n+1` in the file. Inspecting the file may reveal something unique about it at that position, such as inadvertent truncation, or a variation of encoding/token-contents (from the writing routine) that's giving the reader problems.

The `.load_facebook_model()` method is *only* for full-model file written by Facebook's FastText code in its own custom format. **No** specific filepath `fin_bin` that might load via any form of `KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format()` would be appropriate to also load with `FastText.load_facebook_model()`, as the formats are entirely different.

Still, if the method invocation succeeds without error, you *should* have a loaded `FastText` model. A full model object of Gensim class `FastText` does not have a `most_similar()` method – explaning the error you've received – in all versions of Gensim since 3.3.0 (early 2018). Rather, as with the `Word2Vec` & `Doc2Vec` model classes, all operations specific to the set-of-word-vectors should be done through the full model's `.wv` (word-vectors) attribute, which holds an object that's some kind of `KeyedVectors`.

So, if `de_fasttext_model.most_similar()` gives an error that `most_similar` is not a valid attribute, `de_fasttext_model.wv.most_similar()` may work for you instead.